# Counting "How many ways to choose courses to graduate" with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem like, "to graduate you must choose 6 out of 20 courses, but at least 2 out of the 6 courses must be a math course. 8 out of the 20 offered courses are math courses. How many choices are there for which 6 courses to take?"

My reflex is to say $\binom{8}{2} \binom{18}{4}$, but that was given as an example of a *wrong* answer. What is the problem with it?

Comment: If you choose Math 1 and Math 2 as your two required math courses, and then choose Math 3 and 4 and Chem 1 and 2 as your other courses, you get the same result as if you choose Math 3 and Math 4 as your two required math courses and then Math 1 and 2 and Chem 1 and 2 as your other courses; so you are counting the same selection more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count some combinations multiple times. E.g. if you end up with 3 math courses A,B,C, it is counted multiple times, for each combinations where 1 is in the second selection.

The proper way is to count all combinations, and subtract the ones with 0 or 1  math courses, so

$${{20} \choose{6}} - {{12}\choose{6}} - {8\choose 1}{12\choose 5}$$

Comment: Is it fair to generalize problems of the type, "**at least** x need to be y", as requiring some sort of subtraction from the whole set in the solution?

Comment: If you choose $4$ math courses, there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to select two of them, so it would be better to say that you count some combinations more than once if you take more than two math courses.

Comment: @Dorj  It is sometimes convenient to subtract since it simplifies the calculations, as in this case.  Alternatively, you have $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{14}{4} + \binom{6}{3}\binom{14}{3} + \binom{6}{4}\binom{14}{2} + \binom{6}{5}\binom{14}{1} + \binom{6}{6}\binom{14}{0}$$ ways of selecting the courses.  In other cases, it may be simpler to add.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig is right, changed my answer a bit..